# Liquidity Rating

Tags: assets

How is liquidity rating calculated for assets on the Stellar network?

I'm guessing the following factors are important:

-value of the liquidity pool

-value of the limit orders in the order book (those in close proximity to the current market value having more influence)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the liquidity rating chart on stellar.expert, the docs say it is based on the relative slippage of the {asset}/xlm market. The slippage would be determined by the amount of available liquidity in the pool.

More Info: https://stellar.expert/openapi.html#tag/Asset-Info-API/operation/getAssetRating